# is there a log4net for javascript?

Tags: javascript, log4net, logging

i want to log an asp.net , framework 4.0 web application.
i'm using log4net as my logging device and the RollingFileAppender is working great from the code behind.

can log4net log javascript ? 
if yes , how? if not, how do you guys log a javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/), which is based on log4j (as is log4net).

Answer (score 6):

There are several options.

- [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/)
- [log4js](http://log4js.berlios.de/)
- [blackbirdjs](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/) (current favorite)

I liked lumberjack, but can't locate it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I simply use Console.log.  It logs data to the firefox/chrome console.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.log.28object.5B.2C_object.2C_....5D.29

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively 
you can just implement a REST POST Function in an .Net Controller 
an call it via AJAX in your JavaScript Code.

Example given:

**.Net Controller Funktion**

```
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    // POST: LogFromJavaScript
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public void LogFromJavaScript(String errorMessage)
    {
        log.Error("Log from JavaScript: " + errorMessage);
    }
```

**Java Script AJAX Implementation**

```js
function LogFromJavaScript(errorMessage) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: window.urlLogError,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        data: {
             errorMessage: errorMessage
        }
    });
}
```

**And then use it in your JavaScript Code**

```js
window.LogFromJavaScript("Hello JS Log!");
```